# Deforming the affine flag variety into the product of affine Grassmannian and the usual flag variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory

In [Gaitsgory - Construction of central elements in the affine Hecke algebra via nearby cycles](https://doi.org/10.1007/s002220100122) the idea of deforming the affine flag variety into the product of the affine Grassmannian and the usual flag variety is used (for a connected reductive group over a finite field).

Has a similar idea been used in any other papers? It seems like it could be useful in other settings.

Comment: Deforming the affine Grassmanian into the square of the affine Grassmanian is used in geometric Satake.

Comment: @WillSawin, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403698/deforming-the-affine-flag-variety-into-the-product-of-affine-grassmannian-and-th#comment1033919_403698), is there a reference that explains this nicely?

Comment: @LSpice I think any modern reference on geometric Satake will discuss this (under the name "fusion"). I don't know the best one.